# Long arm quilting machines have been on the market for over 40 years

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [WO2015015158A1](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/WO_2015_015158_A1)

Can you get a patent for a product that sells in high volume on the market over the past 40 years?

Answer (score 1):

**Can you get a patent for a product that sells in high volume on the market over the past 40 years?**

Yes. You figure out an improvement and patent the improvement. I'm not passing any judgement of the cited application as I didn't read it thoroughly and I'm not an expert in this field. Do you suppose that the first and only airplane patent went to the Wright brothers?

Also remember, that the cited document is a patent application, not yet a patent. It may never become a patent and if it does, the claims may be significantly narrowed. The application also cites 6 other patents as prior art dating back to 1980.